# Angular 8 HttpClient GET ignoring responseType: 'blob' from swagger API returning {}

Tags: angular, blob, content-type

Specified a API service in swagger 2.0 like so:

```yaml
 /example/my-file:
    get:
      summary: Get this file
      tags:
        - MyFile
      produces:
        - application/octet-stream
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          schema:
            type: file
        400:
          $ref: "#/responses/badRequest"
        404:
          $ref: "#/responses/notFound"
        500:
          $ref: "#/responses/internalServerError"
```

Implemented and can make a Postman GET request that returns the file contents correctly.
I used ng-swagger-gen to generate an angular service call:

```js
getExampleFileResponse(params: ExampleService.GetExampleFileParams): __Observable<__StrictHttpResponse<Blob>> {
    let __params = this.newParams();
    let __headers = new HttpHeaders();
    let __body: any = null;


    let req = new HttpRequest<any>(
      'GET',
      this.rootUrl + `/example/my-file`,
      __body,
      {
        headers: __headers,
        params: __params,
        responseType: 'blob'
      });

    return this.http.request<any>(req).pipe(
      __filter(_r => _r instanceof HttpResponse),
      __map((_r) => {
        return _r as __StrictHttpResponse<Blob>;
      })
    );
  }


  getExampleFile(params: ExampleService.GetExampleFileParams): __Observable<Blob> {
    return this.getExampleFileResponse(params).pipe(
      tap(_r => console.log(_r)),
      __map(_r => _r.body as Blob)
    );
  }
```

When I call from an angular client:

```js
   this.ExampleService.getExampleFile(param)
    .subscribe((f) => {
      saveAs(f, 'example.txt')
    });
```

I get a Blob consisting of 3 bytes: {}\n
Not the file contents. It seems like something in the service is not working correctly. If I put a tap() into the service on the response I can see the response is delivering a Blob with those three bytes and a content-type: application/json, not the application/octet-stream I specified in the API.

Answer (score 0):

OK.Missing piece of information: we were using an interceptor to inject an auth token. We needed to add and Accept: application/json, application/octet-stream, */*' item so the file blob would make it out of the GET. The angular docs state that the default return for a HttpClient.get() is JSON. We just had to specify the accepted return types.